# read SessionStorage in redux createState

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt, sessionstorage

i want to add sessionStorage to my Next.js/React/Redux project in order to get rid of state loss when refreshing the page.
I'm using jwt in order to authenticate the client with my api and putting the jwt in the sessionStorage on login works fine, but i curios where i check if there already is a jwt in the sessionStorage.
My first thought was to add it to the createState function in my reducer where i usually define an empty sessionToken on startup

```
const createState = () => ({
  // ...
  sessionToken: sessionStorage.token || "",
  // ...
})

const gui = (state = createState(), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
  // ...
  }
}
```

But i'm getting
`sessionStorage is not defined`.

Using
`sessionToken: window.sessionStorage || "",`
results in an
`window is not defined` Error

Ok, i thought, i've read something about wrapping sessionStorage in a function [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168615/reactdom-rendertostring-sessionstorage-is-not-defined-window-is-not-defined#41171876)

So i added some functions in a different file and imported them in my reducers, which worked fine.
At least for the imports.

```
export const globalStorage = () => {(insNode = typeof process === 'object' && process.versions && !!process.versions.node) ? global : window}

export const setSessionStorage = (key, value) => sessionStorage.setItem(key, value)
export const getSessionStorage = (key) => sessionStorage.getItem(key)
export const delSessionStorage = (key) => sessionStorage.removeItem(key)
```

But when i tried to call those functions in my reducer

`sessionToken: globalStorage()['sessionStorage'] || "",`

I'm getting:

`(0 , _store.globalStorage) is not a function`

Following this [Tutorial](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/jwt-authentication-with-react-redux/)

my first attempt to access the sessionStorage directly in my createState function should just work fine, but it doesn't.
What am i missing? :/
Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance,
BigZ

Comment: Silly me... sessionStorage is not available server rendered Apps. 
But i can access it from a components `componentDidMount() {}` function.

Comment: Using sessionStorage to store the jwt is not very wise,
When the use closes the tab or the browser the session will be lost together with it's session storage.

A better alternative is to use localStorage.

Comment: Thanks, maybe i think about storing the session in the local storage, and decreasing the time the client is allowed to refresh the token, but for now i'm fine with that behaviour.

Comment: @BigZ I know it's a bit weird, but after a few days, you can add your own answer and mark it as the accepted answer. This way other people stumbling upon this post will get to the answer faster.